# Perl 'or' condition to get hash value in the same key

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a file which contains states in the format such as Gujarat, West Bengal, Jammu & Kashmir and D&D Haveli. I have written a regex to get such names. These names go into the key of a 'year'(2001) such that it is also obtained from the regex such that the year is the key along with various states being the part of the same key.

```
my $stat;
my ($line, $year, $state_name, @state_name);
while($line = <FH>){
    if($line =~ m/^Year (\d+)\S+/){
            $year = $1;
            $stat->{$year} = {};
            next;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^State:,(\w+\s\w+)/){
            $state_name = $1;
            $stat->{$year}{$state_name} = {};
            next;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^State:(\w+)/){
           $state_name = $1;
           $stat->{$year}{$state_name} = {};
           next;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^State:(\w&\w\s\w+)/){
           $state_name = $1;
           $stat->{$year}{$state_name} = {};
           next;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^State:(\w+\s&\s\w+)/){
           $state_name = $1;
           $stat->{$year}{$state_name} = {};
           next;
    }
  }
  print (Dumper(\$stat));
```

I want something now like this to be printed:

```
$VAR2 = {'2001' => {
             'Gujarat' 
             'Jammu & Kashmir'
             'West Bengal'
             'D&D Haveli'                   
              }
          }
```

Instead only West Bengal is printed in the hash with key as 2001 and others are omitted. Please can you suggest where am I going wrong. Thank you.

The edited file is as follows:

```
Year 2001,,,,,,,,
State:,West Bengal,,,,,,,
Year 2001,,,,,,,,
State:,Gujarat,,,,,,,
Year 2001,,,,,,,,
State:,Jammu & Kashmir,,,,,,, and so on.
```

Comment: Are you certain ``Year`` always appears before the other items? if ``Year`` appears late, it will not set ``$year``

Comment: Can you provide the input file as a sample to your post? it seems that it is crucial to finding your bug

Comment: Please see the edit part.. thank you for your quick responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
if($line =~ m/^Year (\d+)\S+/){
            $year = $1;
            $stat->{$year} = {};
            next;
    }
```

Will overwrite the structure under `$stat->{$year}` if it exists, because your "2001" year value appears more than once

A quick fix:

```
if($line =~ m/^Year (\d+)\S+/){
            $year = $1;
            if (not defined $stat->{$year}) { 
             $stat->{$year} = {};
            }
            next;
    }
```

Comment: How about the name of the states? Why is only one name getting displayed? Please can you look into it. Thanks

Comment: You misunderstood my fix, they are not getting overwritten as you a saying, rather you are losing it as the "Year" directive in your file is replacing the existing hash with a new one, which is bad. My fix prevents this replacement.